# InitiateSystemShutdown call on local computer

Tags: c#, windows, system-shutdown, power-off

When using

```
InitiateSystemShutdown(null, null, 0, true, false);
```

some weird things happen. It all works well when I just call the function, also works fine build in my shut-down timer application but the thing is that it does not shut down pc when it's idle for 30+ min and my monitors turn off.

I used other functions to try and shut down the system but I come across the same problem whatever I use. The system does not go to sleep or hibernate or anything like that, it just turns off the displays.

is there a need to "wake" system up somehow prior to calling the function or anything like that.

Method declared as:

```
static extern bool InitiateSystemShutdown(
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpMachinename,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpMessage,
      Int32 dwTimeout,
      bool bForceAppsClosed,
      bool bRebootAfterShutdown);
```

Comment: How are you declared `InitiateSystemShutdown`?

Comment: static extern bool InitiateSystemShutdown(
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpMachinename,
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpMessage,
                    Int32 dwTimeout,
                    bool bForceAppsClosed,
                    bool bRebootAfterShutdown);

Comment: Although the computer is not in sleep/hibernate mode, turning off the monitors does indicate that the PC is turning off some functionality.  Have you tried programmatically waking the machine before initiating the shutdown?

Comment: well that's the one thing i did not try. I ma looking for a good way to do that and will let you know of the results. that's the only thing left that i think of.